# How to add a selector to an existing rule?

Tags: postcss

Is there a way to add a selector to an existing rule with Postcss API? 
Something like `myRule.addSelector(".newSelector")`?

Currently I have to do this:

```
myRule.selector = myRule.selector ? myRule.selector + ", .newSelector" : ".newSelector";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rule.selectors`, which is a property with a `getter` that returns an array of selectors (generated from the `rule.selector` string), and a `setter` that takes an array of selectors (and overwrites the `rule.selector` string).

```
var sels = myRule.selectors; //save the getter returned array so we can modify it with push.
sels.push('.newSelector'); //push returns the new length not the array, that's why we had to save the array in sels.
myRule.selectors = sels; //the setter will join the array elements and overwrite myRule.selector
```

A much shorter version using `concat` (because `concat` returns a new array).

```
myRule.selectors = myRule.selectors.concat('.newSelector');
```

See the PostCSS source [here](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/64aae65e336c783bb1ec334532adba1bc2f33673/lib/rule.es6#L14).

Comment: `var sels = myRule.selectors` returns an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` if no selectors are defined.